# How to play beep in GTK Linux (MonoDevelop)

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm working on a simple project to play a beeping noise in a C# application. I assume you can't use the `System.Console.Beep(100, 100);` function, because you need a console for that to work. Is there an alternative function I can use that let's me specify the frequency and duration of the beep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For playing audio of any kind I usually use https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetCoreAudio/ because it's cross platform and *just works*.